# Apache Configuration on Autoscale Group

Tags: git, apache, google-compute-engine

I am running a Google Compute Group controlled by a load balancer.

I need to make some changes in the Apache Configuration file of VM's that will run under the group. Now if i make a change in one VM, it won't reflect in other instances.

Also, VM start and stop automatically by the load balancer and when a new VM starts it fetches all the files of www folder (required for the website) from a git repository.

How can i make sure that same configuration is copied to all new VM's.

Answer (score 0):

Under that load balancer there is a `Managed Instance Group` where each instance is created from an `Instance Template`. An instance template is just an `Instance Image` with parameters about how big should the VM be, what firewalls should it have and some other settings. The `Autoscaler` is just an additional service added to the managed instance group.

First [create](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images) a new image from a running virtual machine. Then [create](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates#using_custom_or_public_images_in_your_instance_templates) a new template from that image.

You can follow this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/707120/making-changes-to-instance-template) and first [update](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/managed/set-instance-template) your current Managed Instance Group with a new template so Autoscaler will create new instances with your new template:

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed set-instance-template my-instance-group --template=my-new-template
```

Then either recreate all your instances or use the alpha API for [rolling updates](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/instance-groups/managed/rolling-action/). The command bellow just updates a single instance from the

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed recreate-instances my-instance-group --instances=my-first-instance
```

Finally, you might want to take a look into [configuration management](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/google-compute-engine-management-puppet-chef-salt-ansible#top_of_page) software like Ansible that can update on the fly all the instances that are running without any restarts.